# Animation drawer with curve effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation

I need to make an animation drawer with a curve effect. I am new to animation on iOS, so I don't know how to get started. I have taken MMDrawer. I want to open it using the curve effect and close it with a normal curve.

[image: drawr image]

I have added the following new method in MMDrawerController:

```
+(MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock)curevedVisualStateBlock {
    MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock visualStateBlock = ^(MMDrawerController * drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible) {

    };

    return visualStateBlock;
}
```

Comment: I want same curve drawer.

Comment: Curve effect? Are you talking about the odd orange curved shape in your screen-shot, or an animation curve like ease-in, ease-out? And what is MMDrawer? A third party library? If so you might want to put that in the subject of your question so people familiar with the library see your post.

Comment: @DuncanC yes that a third party library which provide sandwich menu, yes i need  Curve effect on center view controller when the silder menu open and it will be remove while slider will close

Comment: WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY CURVE EFFECT?!?!

Comment: @DuncanC you can see the demo of MMDrawer https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController, there will be three controller left menu, right menu,center  i need above image Curve effect while open the right menu

Comment: I'm not going to go download a project to figure out what you are trying to ask. You still haven't explained what you mean by "Curve effect". Are you talking about a curved shape, or timing?

Comment: @DuncanC I am talking about curved shape which you can see clearly on image i posted